# Can't figure out this java Exception: "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1

Tags: java, string

I want this program to ask the user a string and character and then tell the user the number of strings in the character.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for the Scanner Class

/* 

This program ask you to enter a string and a character and then tells you how many times the character appears in the string. 

*/

public class PC5

{ public static void main(String[] args) throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException


   {
      int times = 0;  // To keep track of the times the charcater appears in the String 
      String str1;    // To get the string you want to check
     String str2;   // To get the string for the character you want to check in the String.
      char myChar;  // To get the character from str2 


      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Get the string you want to check 
      System.out.print("Enter the string you want to check: ");
      str1 = keyboard.nextLine();


      // To get the charcater
      System.out.print("Enter the character you want to check: ");
      str2 = keyboard.nextLine();
      myChar = str2.charAt(0); 

     for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)

         {
            if (str2.charAt(i) == myChar)
                    times += 1;


         }


         System.out.println("The number of times the character appears in the string is: " + times);


  }


  }
```

I get this exception when I run this program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)
    at PC5.main(PC5.java:36)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: It means that (duh!) a string index is out of range.  Do a little debugging -- you know what line has the error, so it should be trivial to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something a little more concise, making use of some of the String methods:

```
package com.example.count;
```

import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for the Scanner Class

/*

This program ask you to enter a string and a character and then tells you how many times the character appears in the string.

*/

public class PC5 {

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    int times = 0; // To keep track of the times the charcater appears in
                    // the String
    String str1; // To get the string you want to check
    String str2; // To get the string for the character you want to check in
                    // the String.

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Get the string you want to check
    boolean stopping = false;
    while (!stopping) {
        System.out
                .print("Enter the string you want to check: (enter 'end' to stop)");
        str1 = keyboard.nextLine();
        stopping = "end".equalsIgnoreCase(str1.trim());
        if (!stopping) {

            // To get the character
            System.out.print("Enter the character you want to check: ");
            str2 = keyboard.nextLine();
            if (str2.length() > 1) {
                str2 = str2.substring(0, 1);
            }

            times = 0;
            int loc = -1;
            while ((loc = str1.indexOf(str2, loc + 1)) > -1) {
                times++;
            }

            System.out.println("Results: '" + str2 + "' appears " + times
                    + " times in string " + str1);
        }

    }
    keyboard.close();
    System.out.println("Thanks");

}

}
```

Comment: If this was useful, mark the answer "up" and "answered".

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this, how do I do that?

Comment: CLick on the up arrow symbol on the answer and "check" the answer

Comment: Thank you. I have checked it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant

```
if (str1.charAt(i) == myChar)
```

instead of

```
if (str2.charAt(i) == myChar)
```

As you are iterating over the length of `str1`, and expect `str2.length` to be equal to `1`

Comment: Thank you! I am surprised I did not catch that, yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: I changed it to if (str1.charAt(i) == myChar), but I still get the exception.